# Combining two sentences for title

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english

I want to combine the following sentence:

`Relationship between son and mother, and relationship between daughter and mother`

Into one sentence for title of an article:

`Relationship between son, daughter and mother`

Is grammar and meaning correct?

Comment: _Relationship between mother and children_?

Comment: @oerkelens nope, I have to separate son and daughter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Relationship between son, daughter and mother* does not separate the relationships, because it talks about a single relationship between three parties.

If you need to separate the two individual relationships I'm afraid you'll have to mention them separately.
You *can*, however, make the title shorter by removing *between*; simply play around with word order:

> Mother-daughter, mother-son relationship

Comment: In _titles_ you can leave the _and_ out altogether: _son, daughter, mother relationship_ or _relationship between son, daughter, mother_.

Comment: ok, if i wan to put `and` putting comma before and is right or wrong?

Comment: That comma would be an _Oxford comma_. There's nothing wrong with it, but there is some debate over its use and appropriateness amongst pedants :)

Answer (score 1):

> Single relationship between three parties is what I want: between son, daughter, and mother

Since *between* only works between two parties, and *among* won't work here, I would suggest

**Mother-son-daughter relationship**

Comment: There's some dispute about whether or not [between](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&word=between&resource=Webster%27s&quicksearch=on) only works with two or not. A.D.E.L. 1828 says it works in this context but W.R.U.D. 1913 reverses that decision. [A.H.A. 5th Ed. and Random House Webster's, 2010](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/between) have some interesting usage notes you might want to read that are essentially summarized to whether you want to highlight individuality between the parties or the collective formed among them.